# Firestore indexing and query returns empty results

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

data=> categories collection

```
[
  {
    "category": "toys and games",
    "factory": 1,
    "link": "action-figure-toys-",
    "name": "action figure toys",
    "type": "subcategory"
  },
  {
    "category": "toys and games",
    "factory": 1,
    "link": "action-figure-toys1",
    "name": "action figure toys1",
    "type": "subcategory"
  },
  {
    "category": "",
    "factory": 1,
    "link": "action-figure-toys-",
    "name": "toys and games",
    "type": "category"
  },

]
```

index

```
{
  "collectionId": "categories",
  "fields": [
    { "fieldPath": "name", "mode": "ASCENDING" },
    { "fieldPath": "type", "mode": "ASCENDING" },
    { "fieldPath": "factory", "mode": "ASCENDING" },
    { "fieldPath": "category", "mode": "ASCENDING" },
    { "fieldPath": "subCategory", "mode": "ASCENDING" }
  ]
}
```

query

```
this.db
      .collection('categories', ref =>
        ref
          .where('type', '==', 'category')
          .where('factory', '==', 1)
          .orderBy('name')
          .startAt(this.selected)
          .limit(5)
      ).valueChanges();
```

The query is always returning empty results, if I comment where clauses its working!
if its having only where clause its returning.
combination of where and startAt is causing problem

Comment: Does it return results if you remove the `startAt` and only use the `where`?

Comment: partially yes, if its only where its returning. if orderby is there its not returning anything!